# Python Pillow load font file .ttf from server

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow and I need to load a font from a server, lets say AWS, I bet its possible but I'm not sure how.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("https://criptolibertad.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/img/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf", size=40)
img_draw.multiline_text((20, 200), "Watevs", font=font, fill=(255, 0, 0))
```

It doesn't work. How do I load the font file from a server?

```
OSError at /courses/certificate_preview/1

cannot open resource
```

Comment: as this is url(remote), pls try like `from urllib.request import urlopen
font = ImageFont.truetype(urlopen("https://criptolibertad.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/img/fonts/Roboto-LightItalic.ttf"), size=40)`

Comment: @simpleApp Thanks! it worked. Can you please explain why?

Comment: your font file is in a remote server, so you can't just access it like a file in the local file system. So you need to send a request like ( `GET` following HTTP protocol ) , so `urllib.request` libraries take care of this.